# Ceiling Fan Wiring Help - 2 Switches and 1 Light

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I’m replacing a ceiling fan where there are currently 2 3way switches and 1 separate light fixture. The new ceiling fan has a remote receiver with typical white/black on one side and white/black/blue on other. One connection has 2 black wires, one has 3 white, and other has 2 black and 1 white.

I want to have the light kit on fan (blue wire) to be controlled by the wall switches while the fan has constant power.

See photos of wiring coming out and the remote module. Thank you!

[image: Ceiling Wiring]

[image: Remote Receiver]

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the ceiling box with the bracket removed, as well as the insides of the switch boxes please?